# How to force Android Studio to build with updated NDK library, without having to clean and build entire project?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, shared-libraries, build.gradle

How can I force Android Studio to build my app using the the updated NDK shared library (.so) file, without having to clean the entire project first?

There must be some mechanism by which Android Studio can detect that the shared library has been updated and to use the latest one.  If I do a Build->Clean Project and then do a Run->Run 'app' it will use the new version of the library, but it will also have to do a lot of work that is unnecessary, since none of the java source has changed.  Even a Run->Clean and Rerun'app' won't use the new library.(!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked that Android Studio perfectly detects changes of .so files and rebuilds app when they are changed and you are running the app. Make sure that you have latest Android Studio version and that your .so files are resided in directories

```
app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
app/src/main/jniLibs/x86
```

changing 'main' to your build configuration and armeabi-v7a, x86, .. to your supported architectures, if needed.

Also check that your changed .so files have newer modification time than old ones.

Comment: I am unable to check those things for about 10 days but I know that I am already using the latest Android studio.

Comment: I had to change my setup before leaving the country and now that I've returned and changed things back I cannot reproduce this anymore.  I'm marking Anton's answer as correct bc my system indeed works this way and it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'Preferences' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'Instant run'.

And then just toggle all of the boxes to off.

Comment: Instant run usually is not the problem